# Regarding last year value from the date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with the columns `Sales_Date` and `Sales`. I am looking for a solution to get `Sales` for the last year from the `Sales_Date` Column. `Sales_Date` column has values from the year 2015 onwards.

For example:

| Sales_Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2016 | $25 |
| 1/8/2016 | $57 |
| 1/1/2015 | $125 |
| 1/8/2015 | $21 |

I am looking for the below result set:

| Sales_Date | Sales | LYear_Sales_Date | LYear_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2016 | $25 | 1/1/2015 | $125 |
| 1/8/2016 | $57 | 1/8/2015 | $21 |

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter all data to this year (`WHERE YEAR(Sales.Sales_Date) = 2016`).
2. LEFT JOIN to the same table, combining each date with the same date one year prior (`Sales LEFT JOIN Sales AS Sales_LastYear ON Sales_LastYear.Sales_Date = DATEADD(year, -1, Sales.Sales_Date)`).
3. SELECT the fields that you want (`SELECT Sales.Sales_Date, Sales_LastYear.Sales_Date AS LYear_Sales_Date, ...`).

Replace the LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN, if you want only those records that have a matching last-year record.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `LAG` would work here. Assuming you are always wanting the for the same (day and) month:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Sales_Date,
           Sales,
           LAG(Sales_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY DAY(Sales_Date), MONTH(Sales_Date) ORDER BY YEAR(Sales_Date)) AS LYear_Sales_Date,
           LAG(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY DAY(Sales_Date), MONTH(Sales_Date) ORDER BY YEAR(Sales_Date)) AS LYear_Sales
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Sales_Date,
       Sales,
       LYear_Sales_Date,
       LYear_Sales
FROM CTE
WHERE Sales_Date >= '20160101'
  AND Sales_Date < '20170101';
```